# Can't display data in a component

Tags: vue.js, axios

I have request that returns json data...and i'm trying to display that data in vue component,but it doesn't work. In console.log is everything ok..json is something like:

```
[{"id":1,"body":"Hello, this is my first notification","..bla bla
```

here is my code

```
<template>
    <div class="notification-container">
        <p>{{ notification }}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

    data() {
        return {
            notification: '',
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        axios.get('/notifications').then((response) => {
            this.notification = response.data[0].body;
            console.log(this.notification);
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: cannot see anything wrong with this code.  maybe more details? there are errors in the console?

Comment: sorry it seems kinda right finally, but i dont do it like this, i do it with methods, and call the methods in `created()` or any vue states..

Comment: in console.log is displayed correctly. but when i try something like `array[] = response.data` and then in component '{{ array[0].body }}' it shows me an error `[vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined"`

Comment: do you use any other `this.notification` in your vue.js app ?

Comment: no, just this..

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
<template>
    <div class="notification-container">
        <p>{{ notification /* OR  this.notification[0].body */ }}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

    data() {
        return {
            notification: '',
        }
    },

    methods:{
      showMsg(){
        axios.get('/notifications').then( response => {
            console.log(response);
            this.notification = response.data[0].body;
            /* OR this.notification = response; */
            console.log(this.notification);
        }).catch(e => {
            console.log(e)
        });
      }
    },

    created() { // or mounted()
        this.showMsg();
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: still the same...really confused

Comment: it's confusing, because it should work without problem, i think you share a data names between components, and in this case you should use a statement data approach

Comment: try another data names.. maybe

Comment: try to get the entire response in data, and get it in the template instead in the axios function